# How do I save a NavigationProperty on an Entity from a different context?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, savechanges, navigation-properties

I have two database tables, one for Events and one for RecurrenceRules. Events have a FK that points to a RecurrenceRuleID.

All I want to do is Save an Event AND it's Recurrence rule from a new context, but I can't seem to accomplish this. What am I missing??

```
using (var context = new ScheduledEventEntities())
{
    if (obj.EntityKey == null)
    {
        context.AddObject(obj.EntityKey.EntitySetName, obj);
    }
    else
    {
        var existingObject = context.Events.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Ident == obj.Ident);
        context.ApplyCurrentValues<Event>(obj.EntityKey.EntitySetName, obj);

        // How do I save obj.RecurrenceRule?
    }

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Do you have object tracking enabled ?

Answer (score 2):

I would try it this way:

```
// ...
var existingObject = context.Events.Include("RecurrenceRule")
    .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Ident == obj.Ident);
context.ApplyCurrentValues<Event>(obj.EntityKey.EntitySetName, obj);

// 1st case: Relationship to RecurrenceRule has been removed or didn't exist
if (obj.RecurrenceRule == null)
    existingObject.RecurrenceRule = null;
// 2nd case: Relationship to RecurrenceRule must be set or updated
else
{
     // relationship has changed
    if (existingObject.RecurrenceRule == null ||
        obj.RecurrenceRule.Id != existingObject.RecurrenceRule.Id)
    {
        var existingRecurrenceRule = context.RecurrenceRule
            .SingleOrDefault(r => r.Id == obj.RecurrenceRule.Id);
        if (existingRecurrenceRule != null) // RecurrenceRule exists in DB
        {
            // Update scalar values
            context.ApplyCurrentValues<RecurrenceRule>(
               obj.RecurrenceRule.EntityKey.EntitySetName, obj.RecurrenceRule);
        }
        else // RecurrenceRule does not exist in DB
        {
            // nothing to do, SaveChanges will recognize new RecurrenceRule
            // and create INSERT statement
        }
        // set new relationship
        existingObject.RecurrenceRule = obj.RecurrenceRule;
    }
    else // same relationship: just update scalar values
    {
        // Update scalar values
        context.ApplyCurrentValues<RecurrenceRule>(
            obj.RecurrenceRule.EntityKey.EntitySetName, obj.RecurrenceRule);
    }
}

// ...
```

The problem is indeed that `ApplyCurrentValues` only cares about updating scalar properties but not navigation properties, so you have to handle updating the navigation properties yourself. (Unfortunately updating detached object graphs leads almost always to such tedious code because there is no built-in mechanism in Entity Framework to do this work for you.)

Comment: This will work if you update `ResourceRule` itself but it will not work if you change resource rule reference (change FK value).

Comment: I get the following error: `An object with a key that matches the key of the supplied object could not be found in the ObjectStateManager. Verify that the key values of the supplied object match the key values of the object to which changes must be applied`

Comment: @Rachel: Ladislav's comment is true and you possibly get the exception because you have a changed relationship. I have tried to handle the other cases in my answer (all the if/else cases could probably be combined smarter, but hopefully the logic is clear).

Comment: @Slauma Thank you so much, that is exactly the kind of thing I needed to start going in the right direction. I am fairly new to EF and struggling to work with it has been a challenge. I did need to make a minor modification by detaching the `RecurrenceRule` from the detached object prior to attaching it to the existing object, but I'm so happy that it actually worked! Now to test the other use cases....

Comment: @Slauma Is there some trick to deleting the old `RecurrenceRule` from the database? Just setting the value on the entity to `null` and calling `SaveChanges` correctly removes the FK, but it doesn't remove the old object in the database

Comment: @Rachel: Perhaps simply `if (existingObject.RecurrenceRule != null) context.DeleteObject(existingObject.RecurrenceRule);` before you set `existingObject.RecurrenceRule = null;`.